# Filling Arraylist using recursion in Java

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to fill a list myClassTypes with recursive calls to getMyClassTypes(). But it gets initialized every time there is recursive call to the method. And, I am losing few values because of this. I understand that the problem is with declaring locally: List myClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();
But, I don't want to declare the list at the class level. 
Here is the code I am working with:

```
private List<MyClassType> getMyClassTypes(final String path) throws SVNException {

    final Collection<SVNDirEntry> svnDirectoryEntries = svnRepository.getDir(path, -1, null, (Collection<SVNDirEntry>) null);
    final Iterator<SVNDirEntry> svnDirectoryEntryIterator = svnDirectoryEntries.iterator();
    final List<MyClassType> myClassTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    while (svnDirectoryEntryIterator.hasNext()) {
        final SVNDirEntry entry = svnDirectoryEntryIterator.next();
        final String fileName = entry.getName();

        if (!path.isEmpty() && path.matches(SUB_DIRECTORY_NAME_PATTERN) && fileName.endsWith(".xml")) {                
            final MyClassType myClassType = new MyClassType(path, fileName);
            myClassTypes.add(myClassType);
        }

        /*
         * Check if the entry is a directory recursively.
         */
        if (someCondition) {
            getMyClassTypes((path.equals("")) ? entry.getName() : path + "/" + entry.getName());
        }
    }
    return myClassTypes;
}
```

How to manage the 'myClassTypes' to contain all the values even after 'n times' recursive calls?

Comment: you mean you will call `getMyClassTypes` `n` times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a `List<MyClassType>` instance as argument to the method instead of creating it inside the method.

This way to create just one `ArrayList` instance, and you can even change the return type to `void`.

```
private void getMyClassTypes(final String path, List<MyClassType> myClassTypes) throws SVNException 
{
    final Collection<SVNDirEntry> svnDirectoryEntries = svnRepository.getDir(path, -1, null, (Collection<SVNDirEntry>) null);
    final Iterator<SVNDirEntry> svnDirectoryEntryIterator = svnDirectoryEntries.iterator();

    while (svnDirectoryEntryIterator.hasNext()) {
        final SVNDirEntry entry = svnDirectoryEntryIterator.next();
        final String fileName = entry.getName();

        if (!path.isEmpty() && path.matches(SUB_DIRECTORY_NAME_PATTERN) && fileName.endsWith(".xml")) {                
            final MyClassType myClassType = new MyClassType(path, fileName);
            myClassTypes.add(myClassType);
        }

        /*
         * Check if the entry is a directory recursively.
         */
        if (someCondition) {
            getMyClassTypes((path.equals("")) ? entry.getName() : path + "/" + entry.getName(), myClassTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the return value of the recursive call to the current `myClassTypes` and return it.

```
if (someCondition) {
    myClassTypes.addAll(getMyClassTypes((path.equals("")) ? entry.getName() : path + "/" + entry.getName()));
}
```

Comment: This has the downside of creating multiple `ArrayList` instances when you only need one of them.

Comment: @Eran True. If the recursion depth is too long and it proves to affect performance, then we can pass it as a parameter as you suggest.

Comment: @Eran I felt this is a bit more cleaner (not mutate the input parameter)

Comment: @Eran: Thanks for the idea. Worked fine. That's a pretty solution. (Sorry that I am not allowed to add +1 to answer as my level is too low on stackoverflow)